# custom authorization - roles done, what about users?

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I'm moving from an integrated/windows authenticated system (whereby I used windows groups in the web.config's authorization section, and the web.sitemap as well as using user.identity.name for various per-user features) to an SSO solution which offers authenticated details through the http headers.

I created a very simple custom RoleProvider (overriding IsUserInRole and GetRolesForUser) which worked great for the 'allow roles' sections of the web.config, and roles section of web.sitemap.

I want to do the same for the 'users' part of authorization.. how would I go about doing this? Is it through overriding a different provider? Would it also affect what's returned by user.identity.name?

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Edit - for Jay.

Note this is likely a bit of a hacky and inexperienced fix, but it suited my purpose.. Following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx you can create a class with all the required function definitions, returning false/empty string arrays as necessary.

The only functions I implemented were IsUserInRole and GetRolesForUser. The latter simply hooked into Request.ServerVariables to check the appropriate HTTP header, and format those into a String array as required. The IsUserInRole simply matches a supplied string against the string array returned by GetRolesForUser.

After that, I just referenced the above in the web.config

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="myroleprov" enabled="true">
 <providers>
  <clear/>
  <add name="myroleprov" type="myApp.CustomProviders.myroleprov" applicationName="myApp"/>
 </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I think that's about it? Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you share your code of how you implemeted the custom RoleProvider?

Comment: No problem, see edits.

Comment: Had very similar was missing connection string in the add role provider name section cheers, seems not visible on yours maybe for MVC4 only?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the Membership provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx

Comment: I had a quick look at that, as it seemed to somewhat mirror the roleprovider - but I wasn't sure exactly which methods I would need to override (the majority I would ignore).  I had some success implementing iprincipal and iidentity - using these in the global.asax Application_AuthenticateRequest routine. This fixed user.identity.name but doesn't seem to work with the web.config/sitemap... so I'll return to the membership provider, thanks!

Comment: I've implemented the getUser function which works insofar as I can create the membershipprovider, and use getUser() to return a membershipuser with appropriate username - however this has no affect on my web.sitemap's access rules for users.  Any ideas?